# ASCII chart from csv

Tags: csv, ascii-art

Does someone know some (online) csv to ascii chart converters? I do not need any table, just a diagram.

Here is some example csv.

```
Date,x,y
1.1.18, 1,1
2.1.18, 2,2
3.1.18, 3,4
4.1.18, 3,8
...
```

Comment: Google is your friend. Learn it, use it, love it. Besides asking for vague offsite resources is off topic for SO.

Comment: Just found ascii tables.